# text-shadow:#ffd12b 0 0 0em, #ffd12b 0 0 0em, #ffd12b 0 0 0em, #ffd12b 0 0 0em; This property does not work in opera8

Tags: css

This property does not work in opera8... Is there any replacement to make it work...??

Comment: People still use Opera 8?  I was barely aware *any* version of Opera was around, but it's up to like 11 now, at least...

Answer (score 1):

this would help :

[Font shadows using Raphaël—JavaScript Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628772/font-shadows-using-raphaeljavascript-library)

You can not set shadow to your text using CSS in Opera 8. its just supported in Opera 9.5 or later.